# How to setup and run angular js protractor test in jenkins?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jenkins, protractor

I have following configuration but getting error

ERROR

```
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
18:17:05.892 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
18:17:05.896 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
18:17:05.896 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
18:17:06.187 WARN - Failed to start: SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:4444
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Selenium is already running on port 4444. Or some other service is.
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.start(SeleniumServer.java:492)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:305)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(SeleniumServer.java:245)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:64)
Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1
Selenium standalone server started at http://10.33.24.128:43448/wd/hub
```

**Jenkins commands**

```
## run testing
node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone
node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start > /dev/null 2>&1 &

while ! curl http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status &>/dev/null; do :; done

node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor.conf.js
```

**My configuration file is below**

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: false,

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
    chromeDriver: './node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['tests/specs/*-spec.js'],
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

Comment: What output you get with `node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor.conf.js --troubleshoot`?

Comment: @alecxe DEBUG - Running with --troubleshoot
DEBUG - Protractor version: 3.1.1
DEBUG - Your base url for tests is undefined
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

Answer (score 0):

You have an error message:

> Selenium is already running on port 4444. Or some other service is.

So your tests are failing because Selenium could not be set up, as the port it requires is already in use.

This could be perhaps because another build running in parallel on the same machine, or because Selenium wasn't stopped by a previous build, or some other server is using port 4444.

You need to ensure that this port is free before starting your build.

You can restrict multiple builds running in parallel on the same machine that want to use the same port number with the [Port Allocator plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Port+Allocator+Plugin) or the [Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin).

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to install chrome browser on the slave or chromedriver that comes with protractor has standanlone instance?

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid handling directly this and delegate it to gulp plugin like [gulp-angular-protractor](https://github.com/rochejul/gulp-angular-protractor) to:**

1).Start/stop selenium server

2).And run protractor tests

***Full Example***

**Gulpfile.js**

```
/*jshint node: true, camelcase: false*/
/*global require: true*/

'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
gulpProtractorAngular = require('gulp-angular-protractor');

// Setting up the test task
gulp.task('regression-suite', function(callback) {
    gulp
        .src(['./tests/specs/*spec.js'])
        .pipe(gulpProtractorAngular({
            'configFile': 'protractor.conf.js',
            'debug': false,
            'autoStartStopServer': true
        }))
        .on('error', function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        })
        .on('end', callback);
});
```

**conf.js**

Same as before

**Command Prompt**

```
C:>gulp regression-suite
```

**Jenkins**

Add a step as execute windows command

```
gulp regression-suite
```